# Canonical isomorphism $Hom_{\text{Ab}} (\bigoplus_i A_i, B) \overset{\cong}{\rightarrow} \prod_i Hom_{\text{Ab}}(A_i, B)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, abelian-groups

I want to show that $\text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}} (\bigoplus_i A_i, B) \overset{\cong}{\rightarrow} \prod_i \text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}}(A_i, B)$.

I think the idea is that any homomorphism $\varphi: \bigoplus_i A_i \rightarrow B$ takes a finite sum $\sum_i \alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i \in A_i$ to an element $b \in B$. However, $\varphi$, must be defined on all elements in $A_i$ for all $i$. Hence, if the index set is infinite $\varphi$ can be decomposed to the product, $\prod_i \varphi_i$, of whatever it does to the elements in $A_i$. Since $\varphi_i$ is not necessarily trivial for all but finitely many $i$, it should be a product instead of a direct sum.

I think this is the moral of the story, and that any isomorphism should take $\varphi$ to $\prod_i \varphi_i$. However, I struggle to show it rigorously, could anyone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are canonical "inclusions" $\sigma_j : A_j \to \bigoplus A_i$ (given by $\sigma_j(x) = (x_i)_{i \in I}$ where $x_j = x$ and $x_i = 0$ for $i \ne j$). The system $(\bigoplus A_i, \sigma_j)$ has the universal property of the direct sum (=  coproduct). This means that for each abelian group $B$ and each collection of homomorphisms $f_j : A_j  \to B$ there exists a unique homomorphism $f : \bigoplus A_i \to B$ such that $f \circ \sigma_j = f_j$ for all $j$.

Let us prove it. Define
$$f((x_i)_{i \in I}) = \sum_{j \in I} f_j(x_j). $$
The RHS is well-defined because $x_j \ne 0$ only for finitely many $j$. It is easy to verify that $f$ is a homomorphism. By definition we have $f \circ \sigma_j = f_j$ for all $j$. This shows existence. To show uniqueness, let $f' : \bigoplus A_i \to B$ be any homomorphism such that $f' \circ \sigma_j = f_j$ for all $j$. Let $x = (x_i)_{i \in I} \in \bigoplus A_i$. The set $I_x = \{ i \in I \mid x_i \ne 0 \}$ is finite, thus we get $x = \sum_{j \in I_x} \sigma_j(x_j)$. Hence
$$f'(x) = f'(\sum_{j \in I_x} \sigma_j(x_j)) = \sum_{j \in I_x} f'(\sigma_j(x_j)) = \sum_{j \in I_x} f_j(x_j) = \sum_{j \in I} f_j(x_j) = f(x) .$$

The universal property is essentially what you want to prove.

Define
$$\phi : \text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}} (\bigoplus_i A_i, B) \to \prod_i \text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}}(A_i, B), \phi(f) = (f \circ \sigma_i)_{i \in I} .$$
By the universal property of the direct sum $\phi$ is a bijection.

It is moreover easy to verify that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Thus $\phi$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I am wondering, maybe it is a silly question, but why would RHS not be well-defined if $x_j≠0$ for infinitely many $j$?

Comment: @mNugget There are no infinite sums in abelian groups. For example take $x_i = 1 \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ok, i see. Thanks:)